# PyCaret cannot import name '_check_param_grid' from 'sklearn.model_selection._search'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycaret

Hi I have been trying to fix this error that keeps coming up. I have tried everything online like reinstalling sklearn to the proper version documented on the GitHub repo and website. there were many more cannot recall but if anyone has any recommendations please let me know.

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> input In [225], in <cell line: 3>()
> 1 import pycaret
> 2 # from pycaret.clustering import setup, create_model, evaluate_model, predict_model, save_model, load_model
> ----> 3 from pycaret.clustering import *
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pycaret\clustering_*init*_.py:1,
> in 
> ----> 1 from pycaret.clustering.oop import ClusteringExperiment
> 2 from pycaret.clustering.functional import (
> 3     setup,
> 4     create_model,    (...)
> 24     set_current_experiment,
> 25 )
> 27 **all** = [
> 28     "ClusteringExperiment",
> 29     "setup",    (...)
> 50     "set_current_experiment",
> 51 ]
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pycaret\clustering\oop.py:2,
> in 
> 1 from pycaret.internal.pycaret_experiment.utils import MLUsecase
> ----> 2 from pycaret.internal.pycaret_experiment.unsupervised_experiment import (
> 3     _UnsupervisedExperiment,
> 4 )
> 5 import pycaret.internal.patches.sklearn
> 6 import pycaret.internal.patches.yellowbrick
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pycaret\internal\pycaret_experiment\unsupervised_experiment.py:20,
> in 
> 18 from pycaret.internal.preprocess.preprocessor import Preprocessor
> 19 from pycaret.internal.pycaret_experiment.utils import highlight_setup, MLUsecase
> ---> 20 from pycaret.internal.pycaret_experiment.tabular_experiment import _TabularExperiment
> 21 from pycaret.internal.pipeline import (
> 22     Pipeline as InternalPipeline,
> 23     estimator_pipeline,
> 24     get_pipeline_fit_kwargs,
> 25 )
> 26 from pycaret.internal.utils import to_df, infer_ml_usecase, mlflow_remove_bad_chars
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pycaret\internal\pycaret_experiment\tabular_experiment.py:18,
> in 
> 16 import pycaret.internal.patches.sklearn
> 17 import pycaret.internal.patches.yellowbrick
> ---> 18 import pycaret.internal.persistence
> 19 import pycaret.internal.preprocess
> 20 import scikitplot as skplt  # type: ignore
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pycaret\internal\persistence.py:9,
> in 
> 6 from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
> 7 from pycaret.internal.utils import get_logger
> ----> 9 from pycaret.utils.time_series.forecasting.pipeline import *add_model_to_pipeline
> 10 from pycaret.internal.pycaret_experiment.utils import MLUsecase
> 13 def deploy_model(
> 14     model, model_name: str, authentication: dict, platform: str = "aws", prep_pipe*=None
> 15 ):
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pycaret\utils\time_series\forecasting\pipeline.py:3,
> in 
> 1 from copy import deepcopy
> 2 from sktime.forecasting.base import BaseForecaster
> ----> 3 from sktime.forecasting.compose import ForecastingPipeline
> 4 from sktime.forecasting.compose import TransformedTargetForecaster
> 7 class PyCaretForecastingPipeline(ForecastingPipeline):
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sktime\forecasting\compose_*init*_.py:28,
> in 
> 8 **all** = [
> 9     "ColumnEnsembleForecaster",
> 10     "EnsembleForecaster",    (...)
> 24     "make_reduction",
> 25 ]
> 27 from sktime.forecasting.compose._column_ensemble import ColumnEnsembleForecaster
> ---> 28 from sktime.forecasting.compose._ensemble import (
> 29     AutoEnsembleForecaster,
> 30     EnsembleForecaster,
> 31 )
> 32 from sktime.forecasting.compose._multiplexer import MultiplexForecaster
> 33 from sktime.forecasting.compose._pipeline import (
> 34     ForecastingPipeline,
> 35     TransformedTargetForecaster,
> 36 )
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sktime\forecasting\compose_ensemble.py:21,
> in 
> 19 from sktime.forecasting.base._base import DEFAULT_ALPHA
> 20 from sktime.forecasting.base._meta import _HeterogenousEnsembleForecaster
> ---> 21 from sktime.forecasting.model_selection import temporal_train_test_split
> 22 from sktime.utils.stats import (
> 23     _weighted_geometric_mean,
> 24     _weighted_max,
> 25     _weighted_median,
> 26     _weighted_min,
> 27 )
> 28 from sktime.utils.validation.forecasting import check_regressor
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sktime\forecasting\model_selection_*init*_.py:22,
> in 
> 20 from sktime.forecasting.model_selection._split import SlidingWindowSplitter
> 21 from sktime.forecasting.model_selection._split import temporal_train_test_split
> ---> 22 from sktime.forecasting.model_selection._tune import ForecastingGridSearchCV
> 23 from sktime.forecasting.model_selection._tune import ForecastingRandomizedSearchCV
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sktime\forecasting\model_selection_tune.py:13,
> in 
> 11 from sklearn.base import clone
> 12 from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid, ParameterSampler, check_cv
> ---> 13 from sklearn.model_selection._search import _check_param_grid
> 14 from sklearn.utils.metaestimators import if_delegate_has_method
> 16 from sktime.exceptions import NotFittedError
>
> ImportError: cannot import name '_check_param_grid' from
> 'sklearn.model_selection._search' (C:\Users\

hashi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_search.py)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem might be related to the version of scikit-learn package.

Comment: Maybe answers that aren't definite answers to the problem should be comments rather than answers?